# Set DataSource Attribute TableName dynamically

Tags: c#, automated-tests, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how the data setup occurs in CodedUI/MSTest

I understand that the `DataSource` attribute on this test method is created at compile-time, which is why I can only pass `testCaseIdString` in as a constant.

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource(TestCaseFullName, TfsConnectionName, testCaseIdString, DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
public void DynamicTest()
{
    //stuff
}
```

However, I'd like to get the `testCaseIdString` dynamically through the TestContext. Which I have been able to do to some extent using:

```
string dynamicTestCaseId = TestContext.Properties["__Tfs_TestCaseId__"].ToString();
```

However, this is retrieved after I would have declared in the `DataSource` attribute.

**How can I retrieve the `TestContext` properties and assign the testCaseID dynamically within the `DataSource` attribute?**

Comment: Out of the box mstest doesn't support "static test case generation". You could combine [mstest and T4](https://victorhurdugaci.com/dynamic-tests-with-mstest-and-t4) to achieve "dynamic test case generation". [Pex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830026/create-unit-test-methods-dynamically-during-runtime-in-mstest) is another option.

Comment: @lloyd thanks for the reply, the issue I'm facing is that this needs to report to MTM and TFS including the tmi.trx file that is generated from the runs. Will the reporting and connectivity functionality remain relatively the same with those options you've outlined?

Comment: I'm not sure. [Time box it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeboxing) and provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example if you have any issues in a new question.